# No encryption protocol is supported in nginx even though I have the key and cert

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

This was working well but for some reason it started not to work. I have the ssl files in a 777 folder. Here is my nginx conf:

```
     keepalive_timeout 70;

     ssl_certificate     /path/to/crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;  #these are both correct
     #the rest of this file is shown as it is

     ssl_session_timeout 1d;
     ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;

     #ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

     ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     #I had 'modern' (no TLSv1). Tried to add it to see if it would fix but it didn't
     ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256$
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

     add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

     ssl_stapling on;
     ssl_stapling_verify on;

     ## verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermedia$
     #ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/root_CA_cert_plus_intermediates;

     #resolver <IP DNS resolver>;
```

And here are the logs of cipherscan on my website:

```
Certificate: untrusted,  bits,  signature
TLS ticket lifetime hint: 
OCSP stapling: not supported
Cipher ordering: server
Curves ordering: none - fallback: no
Renegotiation test error
Supported compression methods test error

TLS Tolerance: no
Fallbacks required:
big-SSLv3 config not supported, connection failed
big-TLSv1.0 config not supported, connection failed
big-TLSv1.1 config not supported, connection failed
big-TLSv1.2 config not supported, connection failed
small-SSLv3 config not supported, connection failed
small-TLSv1.0 config not supported, connection failed
small-TLSv1.0-notlsext config not supported, connection failed
small-TLSv1.1 config not supported, connection failed
small-TLSv1.2 config not supported, connection failed
v2-big-TLSv1.2 config not supported, connection failed
v2-small-SSLv3 config not supported, connection failed
v2-small-TLSv1.0 config not supported, connection failed
v2-small-TLSv1.1 config not supported, connection failed
v2-small-TLSv1.2 config not supported, connection failed
```

When I do a `sudo service nginx restart` no error is referred and it starts just as it should. Does anyone have any idea on what might be happening? Thank you very much for your help

When accessed via firefox I get "Secure Connection Failed" and when accessed through chrome I get "SSL connection error: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". **Could this be due to nameservers?** I recently tried to enable cloudflare so I'm in doubt whether traffic is being badly manipulated.

Comment: please post a full version of your nginx config. I assume there might be an error with the *listen* parameter set in your config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256$
> ```

This is a very restrictive set of ciphers you are trying to use here. These are all GCM ciphers which are only supported with TLS 1.2 - which means that your option to accept TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 traffic is useless. And it might be that these ciphers are not supported by all browsers too. See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Intermediate_compatibility_.28default.29 for recommended configurations.

Apart from that the syntax you show is wrong, i.e. it line should not end with `$` but `';`. But that might be a typo in your question only.